# Calling a SoapUI request from a different program

Tags: soapui

I have a SoapUI project (an XML file).

The project has an operation (a SOAP operation). Under this operation, I have a **request**.

My question, is there a way to run my SoapUI **request** from my other programs (written in a programming language of my choice)?

If this is possible, how would I pass parameters to the **request**? And obviously, I want to get the result too.

Is this even possible? I hope so, because SoapUI is making it really easy to create SOAP requests with all kinds of stuff (such as auth). It would be pity if I'd have to do all that heavy lifting myself.

Comment: What is the exact issue that you face? SoapUI allows to execute the project using UI or command line as well. Why do you need another programming language to execute?

Comment: Or see if this junit integration using java helps - https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/junit/junit-integration.html